# I am an Indian citizen. Can I apply for UK visa without submitting passport since I have to travel to another country in that period?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, paperwork

I am an Indian. I am planning a trip to UK and need to apply for a visitor visa. But since I have a Japan trip planned between now and my UK trip, I don't have enough time for a regular UK visa application which could take up to 14 working days. I know if the fast track option, but it is quite expensive. Is there a way to apply for UK visa without submitting my passport?

Answer (score 5):

You can and this option is available only if you are not using the priority or super priority options. Refer to https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/india/user_pay_services.html#keep-my-passport-when-applying

Answer (score 2):

No, unless you have an alternative valid travel document that you can submit with the application. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Comment: Not correct, see answer from Bharg below.